# Changing from javaexec to project.test in build.gradle for a Cucumber Java project

Tags: gradle, cucumber, build.gradle, cucumber-java

I want to implement a retry option for my testing framework. I did some digging around and discovered the option can be incorporated but not as I had the project. I have been trying to convert it from using a javaexec structure to using project.test, but when I go to call my gradle task none of my test steps are called. I may be overlooking something, I am not too familiar with this method of implementation, so any advice would be helpful.

Here is my existing test execution code:

```
task smoke() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast { runTests('smoke') }
}
task regression() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast { runTests('regression') }
}
task newWork() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast { runTests('newWork') }
}

private ExecResult runTests(String testType) {
    javaexec {
        mainClass = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
        classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        args = ['--plugin', 'pretty',
                '--plugin', 'json:output/reports/report.json',
                '--plugin', 'html:output/reports/html',
                '--tags', ('@' + testType), '--glue', 'stepDefinitions', 'src/test/resources/features',
                '--tags', 'not @disabled']
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried implementing:

```
task smoke() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast { runTests('smoke') }
}
task regression() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast { runTests('regression') }
}
task newWork() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast { runTests('newWork') }
}

private void runTests(String testType) {
    project.test {
        workingDir = file('src/test/resources')
        systemProperty 'cucumber.options', "--tags @${testType} --glue stepDefinitions:src/test/java/stepDefinitions"
        retry {
            maxRetries = 3
            maxFailures = 20
            failOnPassedAfterRetry = false
        }
        reports {
            reports.html.required = true
            reports.html.destination = file('alice/JavelinTAF/output/reports/html')
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked logs and tried adding debugging statements but have not been able to find what may be wrong. It seems as though the tests are not being found at all. The build is successful but no tests are run. I also have not been able to add the output for .json reports in the relevant section as it throws an error, but that is not as big a deal right now. I have been struggling to find documentation or examples of this, so any advice or examples would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of Cucumber JVM are you using?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you're not invoking io.cucumber.core.cli.Main anywhere in your project setup. And I'm not sure how to do that in Gradle. It also looks like `test-retry` doesn't support the JUnit Platform properly. It can only rerun class based tests.

Comment: You may have some luck generating runners for individual scenarios using: https://github.com/gradle/cucumber-companion

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje I am using 7.13.0 for all cucumber dependencies. Oh that is true that the new structure does not incorporate io.cucumber.core.cli.Main anywhere. I can try investigating if there is a way to do that with the project.test structure. 
I had looked into rerun as an option, but retry looked so much cleaner from what I could learn. 
I will take a look at the cucumber-companion as well and see if that suites my needs. Thanks for the advice! I'll report back if anything moves me forward.

Comment: I have been working on this the past few days and have not come up with anything functional yet. I have tried adding a CucumberTestRunner class to make use of the TestNG IRetryAlalyzer but it does not seem to be working properly or making use of the runner class at all. I've also gone back to using javaexec because without it my test cases never seem to be found, but I feel there is a conflict between using that and getting gradle to recognize my task as a testing task, perhaps. I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: If the companion plugin didn't help, then I've got nothing. I'm not a Gradle expert, but last time I looked at it, Gradle is very limited in what it actually supports internally. If it's not a single test per method Gradle doesn't understand it.

Comment: I can give the companion another try. Currently I am not using JUnit, but I can look into if it is something I can add without having to completely restructure my project.